# Compute the solution $\phi_t \overrightarrow x_0 = e^{At} \overrightarrow x_0$ to the system $x' = -x + 4y$ and $y' = -4x - y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Compute the solution $\phi_t \overrightarrow x_0 = e^{At} \overrightarrow x_0$ to the system $x' = -x + 4y$ and $y' = -4x - y$

The characteristic equation i found is $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 17$...The eienvalues are -1+- 4i....can anyone help me to move forward since i do not know how to find the eigenvector from non real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues are:

$$\lambda_{1,2} = -1 ~ \pm ~ 4i$$

To find the eigenvectors, we solve:

$$[A - \lambda I]v_i = 0$$

For the first eigenvalue, we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 -(-1 + 4i) & 4\\-4 & -1 -(-1 + 4i)\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0 \implies \begin{bmatrix}- 4i & 4\\-4 & - 4i\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

Finding the RREF $(R_2 = R_2 + iR_1, R_1 = R_1/4, R_1 = R_1/i)$ of this matrix yields:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & i\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

This gives us the eigenvector:

$$v_1 = (-i, 1)$$

Since we have a complex conjugate eigenvalue, the other eigenvector is:

$$v_2 = (i, 1)$$

There are many ways to find $e^{A t}$. We can do:

$$e^{A t} = P e^{D t}P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-i & i\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}e^{(-1 + 4i)t} & 0\\0 & e^{(-1 - 4i)t}\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{i}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}\\-\dfrac{i}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} = e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}\cos 4t & \sin 4t\\-\sin 4t & \cos 4t\end{bmatrix}$$

We could have also found a fundamental matrix $M(t)$ and formed $e^{At} = M(t) M^{-1}(0)$ and other approaches.

**Update**

If we plot the phase portrait for this system, we have:

[image]

What do you notice about any initial condition? What can you say about the stability?

Comment: i have a related question on another post...if you would like to take a look, it would be great...the link is the following http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702728/finding-a-value-a-for-topologically-conjugacy-between-two-flows and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702582/given-a-solution-to-find-a-matrix