# Given a solution to find a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

For $e^{At} = 1/2\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}+e^{-t} & e^{2t} - e^{-t} \\ e^{2t}-e^{-t}  & e^{2t}+e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$ for all t $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. how to find A?

Comment: I think something is amiss in the question. Are we supposed to find determinant of the matrix or differentiate?

Comment: Find matrix A..

Comment: $e$ raised to the power of matrix $A$ still doesn't make sense.

Comment: What differential equation does $e^{At}$ solve?

Comment: the solution is written on right hand side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix exponential is given by:

$$\tag 1 e^{At} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_k A^k$$

where the $\alpha_i$'s  are determined from the set of equations given by the eigenvalues of A, as:

$$\tag 2 e^{\lambda_i t} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_k \lambda_i^k$$

We are given:

$$e^{At} = 1/2\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}+e^{-t} & e^{2t} - e^{-t} \\ e^{2t}-e^{-t}  & e^{2t}+e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$$

From this, we know we have a characteristic polynomial of:

$$\lambda^2-\lambda -2 = 0 \implies \lambda_1 = -1, ~\lambda_2 = 2$$

From $(1)$, we have $n = 2$ (the number of eigenvalues) and can write:

$$\tag 3 e^{At} = \alpha_0 ~I + \alpha_1 ~ A$$

From $(2)$, we can write:

$$\alpha_0 - \alpha_1 = e^{-t} \\ \alpha_0 + 2 \alpha_1 = e^{2t}$$

Solving this $~2x2~$ yields:

$$\alpha_0 = \dfrac{1}{3} e^{2t} + \dfrac{2}{3}e^{-t}, ~~ \alpha_1 = \dfrac{1}{3}e^{2t} - \dfrac{1}{3}e^{-t}$$

From $(3)$, we have:

$$A = \dfrac{e^{At}-\alpha_0 I}{\alpha_1}$$

Substituting all of the information, we arrive at:

$$A = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, we can use this calculated $A$ and determine $e^{At}$, yielding:

$$e^{At} = 1/2\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}+e^{-t} & e^{2t} - e^{-t} \\ e^{2t}-e^{-t}  & e^{2t}+e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: after revising this, you might want to visit the following link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702728/finding-a-value-a-for-topologically-conjugacy-between-two-flows

Comment: how did you find A again since $\alpha_0$ is not a matrix...how can you use a matrix - a number?

Comment: got it!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\left.\mbox{Note that}\ A = \totald{\pars{\expo{At}}}{t}\right\vert_{t\ =\ 0}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large A} &=
> \totald{}{t}\bracks{\half\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
> \expo{2t} + \expo{-t} & \expo{2t} - \expo{-t}
> \\[2mm]
> \expo{2t} - \expo{-t}  & \expo{2t} + \expo{-t}
> \end{array}}}_{t\ =\ 0}
> =
> \half\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
> 2\expo{2t} - \expo{-t} & 2\expo{2t} + \expo{-t}
> \\[2mm]
> 2\expo{2t} + \expo{-t}  & 2\expo{2t} - \expo{-t}
> \end{array}}_{t\ =\ 0}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \color{#00f}{\large\half\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 3
> \\[2mm]
> 3  & 1
> \end{array}}}
> \end{align}