# Finding a value a for topologically conjugacy between two flows

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let A be a hyperbolic matrix such that all solutions of $\overrightarrow x' = A \overrightarrow x $ tend to the origin at t goes to infinity, and suppose B = $\begin{bmatrix}a-3 & 5 \\ -2 & a+3\end{bmatrix}$. For which values of a are the flows of $\overrightarrow x' = A \overrightarrow x $ and $\overrightarrow y' = B \overrightarrow y $ topologically conjugate?

i found the characteristic equation as $\lambda^2 - (a+3) \lambda + a^2 + 1$. Then,  i found $$\lambda = \frac{(a+3)+-\sqrt(-(a+3)^2 - 4(a^2+1))}{2}$$ since A be a hyperbolic matrix such that all solutions of $\overrightarrow x' = A \overrightarrow x $ tend to the origin at t goes to infinity, the solution of A is sink or spiral sink...how do I find a?

Comment: topologically conjugate means that the behaviors of solution near equilibrium points are the same as t goes to infinity

Comment: can u show your steps for your calculation for B?

Comment: ur answers look right to me ... could you show your steps for your B?

Comment: sure....!!!go for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}a-3 & 5 \\ -2 & a+3\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues, we set up and solve:

$$|B - \lambda~I| = 0 \implies \begin{vmatrix}a-3 -\lambda & 5 \\ -2 & a+3 -\lambda\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

This yields:

$$(a-3 - \lambda)(a+3-\lambda) + 10 = 0 \implies \lambda^2 -2 a \lambda + a^2 + 1 = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2} = a ~ \pm ~ i$$

Since we have a complex conjugate eigenvalue, what do you need to set $a$ to in order to have a sink or spiral sink?

Comment: yes...but I have the same set up as you...could you some more intermediate steps?

Comment: for example, where is your $a^2$ term?

Comment: could you show the rest as well? to set a in order to have a sink or spiral sink?

Comment: after your first setup, I got $\lambda^2 - (a+3)\lambda + a^2 + 1$...this is different from your second step though

Comment: a < 0 right????

Comment: did you see my intermediate step...is my right?

Comment: i am wondering could you help me solve several small questions in the following: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702561/a-set-a-subset-mathbbr2-containing-more-than-one-point-that-is-invariant , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702595/find-a-nonhyperbolic-matrix-which-satisfies-certain-conditions before you go to bed? This is kind of urgent...if u could help I will greatly appreciate it

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: they are finding examples might not be very difficult for you